# Force free shipping for WooCommerce Subscription recurring orders only

Tags: php, wordpress, e-commerce

I'm using WooCommerce Subscriptions and here's what I want to do:

1. Use free shipping for all recurring orders even if the minimum isn’t met.
2. Get rid of any other free shipping choices (like free priority/express) for recurring orders. Only the one free option should remain.
3. Make sure that the free shipping choice for the recurring order doesn't change the shipping methods available for the parent order.

This is the code I came up with and it works. Before I put it on a production site, is there a better solution than changing the flat rate like this? Any potential issues using this solution?

```
function recurring_items_free_shipping( $rates, $package ) {
    if (class_exists( 'WC_Subscriptions_Cart' )) {

        // Flat rate shipping IDs
        $flat_rates = array( 'flat_rate:1' );

        // Flag to check if a recurring item is in the cart
        $has_recurring_item = false;

        foreach ( WC()->cart->cart_contents as $cart_item ) {
            if (\WC_Subscriptions_Cart::cart_contains_subscription( $cart_item['product_id'] )) {
                $has_recurring_item = true;
                break; // Break the loop if a recurring item is found
            }
        }

        // If a recurring item is found, update shipping rates
        if ($has_recurring_item) {
            //print_r($rates);
            foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
                // Make sure this is the recurring shipping methods
                if (! empty( WC()->cart->recurring_carts )) {
                    // Unset all rates except those in the $flat_rates array.
                    if (! in_array( $rate->id, $flat_rates )) {
                        unset( $rates[ $rate_id ] );
                    } else {
                        // Set the cost and label for 'flat_rate:1' to enable free shipping
                        $rates[ $rate_id ]->cost = 0;
                        $rates[ $rate_id ]->label = 'Free shipping';
                        // Change method_id otherwise future orders will use flat rate pricing
                        $rates[ $rate_id ]->method_id = 'free_shipping';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\recurring_items_free_shipping', 10, 2 );
```